# karma/jasmine/angular – Trouble unit-testing directives AngularJS that use templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Template for the directive is not loaded.

Now I'm getting:

```
$ karma start test/config/karma.config.js 
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.4)]: Connected on socket PC84tuDRk52x9Cq4G_xp
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.4) Directive pagination test has the number of the page as text in each page item FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET static/src/partials/pagination.tpl.html
```

I'm trying to unittest a simple directives. Directive declared in the directives.js.

```
angular.module('app.directives', [])
.directive('pagination', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            numPages: "=",
            currentPage: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'static/src/partials/pagination.tpl.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope) {
            // ...
        }
    };
});
;
```

Directory structure:

```
static
├── Gruntfile.js
├── bower.json
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── controllers.js
│   ├── directives.js
│   ├── partials
│   │   ├── add.tpl.html
│   │   ├── edit.tpl.html
│   │   ├── list.tpl.html
│   │   ├── pagination.tpl.html
│   │   ├── secpage.tpl.html
│   │   └── toolbar.tpl.html
│   └── services.js
├── test
│   ├── config
│   │   └── karma.config.js
│   └── unit
│       ├── button-directive.test.js
│       ├── pagination-directive.test.js
│       └── t1.test.js
└── vendor
```

Test file pagination-directive.test.js

```
describe('Directive pagination test', function () {

    var $rootScope,
        $compile,
        element,
        lis;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app.directives'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('templates'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $compile = _$compile_;

        $rootScope.numPages = 5;
        $rootScope.currentPage = 3;

        element = $compile('<pagination num-pages="numPages" current-page="currentPage"></pagination>')($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();

        lis = function() {return element.find('li');};
    }));
    it('has the number of the page as text in each page item', function() {
        for (var i=1; i<=$rootScope.numPages; i++) {
            expect(lis().eq(i).text()).toEqual(''+i);
        }
    });
});
```

And karma config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
        '../../vendor/angular/angular.js',
        '../../vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        '../../vendor/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        '../../vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        '../../vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',

        '../../src/*.js',
        '../../src/partials/*.html',

        '../unit/*.test.js',
    ],

    exclude: [],

    preprocessors: {
        "../../src/**/*.html": "ng-html2js"
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: "../../",
      prependPrefix: "static/",
      moduleName: "templates"
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Help me, please.

Source code:
https://github.com/Istergul/directive_test

Comment: Can you provide sample of your code on GitHub? It takes to much time to recreate your project structure. From my side – I have also problem with **ng-html2js** and simple **html2js** works for me.

Comment: @krzysztof-safjanowski I put the source code here https://github.com/Istergul/directive_test

Comment: Little pull request is waiting for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge config, than `./static/node_modules/karma/bin/karma start static/test/config/karma.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '../../',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        './vendor/angular/angular.js',
        './vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        './vendor/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        './vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        './vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        './src/*.js',
        './src/partials/*.html',
        './test/unit/*.test.js',
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        "./src/partials/*.html": "ng-html2js"
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      moduleName: "templates"
    }
  });
};
```

And for some reason **ng-html2js** can't understand changes for interpolateProvide provider

```
.config(["$interpolateProvider", function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

move karma.config.js under static folder.

```
static
├── karma.config.js
```

karma.config.js

```
files: [
    'vendor/angular/angular.js',
    'vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'vendor/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
    'vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',

    'src/*.js',
    'src/partials/*.html',

    'test/unit/*.test.js',
],

preprocessors: {
    "src/**/*.html": "ng-html2js"
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  stripPrefix: "src/",
  moduleName: "templates"
},
```

directives

```
templateUrl: 'partials/pagination.tpl.html',
```

Hope this helps.